# List tables in a postgres schema with no recent activity (stale tables)

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to list all the tables in a schema that have had no new records and now updates in the last x days? Is there any system functions, or information_schema meta that records an timestamp of activity in a table?

The only way I can see to do this is to get a list of tables then loop through them one by one via script.

Comment: That information is not available.

Comment: have triggers for every and save the last datetime when something changes, but you would get the last SELECT query, it should on the long rin be faster than any loop

Comment: Postgres does not collect that information. What you are asking for is available only if you store the last DML operation date, either in each row or a table with specific for that data. This would not however give you when the last Select occurred on the table.